# How to customize Javadoc output for the Java 9+

Tags: java, classloader, javadoc, java-11, java-9

I want to modify the Javadoc output, for this purpose I create a custom Doclet that reuse the default one and wrap DocletEnvironment in my proxy class that contains my custom filtering logic.

**NOTE: java 11 javadoc API used**

My Doclet class:

```
public class MyDoclet implements Doclet {
    private final HtmlDoclet htmlDoclet;

    public MyDoclet() {
        htmlDoclet = new HtmlDoclet(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run(DocletEnvironment docEnv) {
        var proxy = new DocletEnvironmentProxy(docEnv);
        return htmlDoclet.run(proxy);
    }

//other code...
}
```

My DocletEnvironment proxy class:

```
public class DocletEnvironmentProxy implements DocletEnvironment  {
    public static final String TAG = "peek_me";
    private final DocletEnvironment environment;
    private Set<? extends Element> filteredElements;

    public DocletEnvironmentProxy(DocletEnvironment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<? extends Element> getIncludedElements() {
        if (filteredElements == null) {
            filteredElements = filterElements(environment.getIncludedElements());
        }
        return filteredElements;
    }
//other code...
}
```

But when I try to run it I get:
*java.lang.ClassCastException: class mypackage.DocletEnvironmentProxy cannot be cast to class jdk.javadoc.internal.tool. DocEnvImpl (mypackage.DocletEnvironmentProxy is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @3dfc5fb8; jdk.javadoc.internal.tool.DocEnvImpl is in module jdk.javadoc of loader 'app')*

I found the [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8224092) related to it and interesting [comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8224092?focusedCommentId=14306030&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14306030) for it, which says "this is not a recognized way to perform customization"

I spent a lot of time looking for the "correct" description of the customization approach but did not find anything related to it. Only some guides from Oracle on the basic [Doclet API](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/using-new-doclet.html) usages.

Maybe someone knows where I can find the "correct" approach or already solved the Doclet customization issue?